# Implementing Rendertron with Angular 5 - Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular5, firebase-hosting

I'm attempting to implement Rendertron with an Angular 5 website, hosted by Firebase. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANyOZIcGvB8) closely. I was able to get everything working up until he started implementing custom functions in the **index.js**. He starts this at 9:12 in the video.

Here's the code in the **index.js** file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = require('url');
const app = express();

const appUrl = 'project-name.firebaseapp.com';
const renderUrl = 'https://render-tron.appspot.com/render';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

function generateUrl(request) {
  return url.format({
    protocol: request.protocol,
    host: appUrl,
    pathname: request.originalUrl
  });
}

function dectectBot(userAgent) {
  const bots = [
    'bingbot',
    'yandexbot',
    'duckduckbot',
    'slurp',

    'twitterbot',
    'facebookexternalhit',
    'linkedinbot',
    'embedly',
    'baiduspider',
    'pinterest',
    'slackbot',
    'vkShare',
    'facebot',
    'outbrain',
    'W3C_Validator'
  ]

  const agent = userAgent.toLowerCase();

  for (const bot of bots) {
    if (agent.indexOf(bot) > -1) {
      console.log('bot detected', bot, agent)
      return true
    }
  }

  console.log('no bots found')
  return false

}

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const isBot = dectectBot(req.headers['user-agent']);

  if (isBot) {
    const botUrl = generateUrl(req);

    fetch(`${renderUrl}/${botUrl}`)
      .then(res => res.text() )
      .then(body => {
        res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
        res.set('Vary', 'User-Agent');
        res.send(body.toString());
      });
  } else {
    fetch(`https://${appUrl}`)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(body => {
        res.send(body.toString());
      })
  }
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I reference the **app** variable in my **firebase.json** file like this:

```
"public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "app"
      }
    ],
```

My IDE doesn't show any errors in the code, but I'm seeing the following errors when I attempt to deploy functions:

```
36:3   warning  Arrow function expected no return value     consistent-return
   89:5   error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
   91:13  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
   98:5   error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
  100:13  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 5 problems (4 errors, 1 warning)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2018-02-19T15_12_33_236Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I'm sure it's not best practice, but I turned off the linter in my firebase.json file. Once I did that, I could deploy functions.

However, when I deploy hosting files, I get the following error:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from [subschema 0],[subschema 1]
```

I found the following solution to that error: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/27

The problem is that I'm very new to Javascript and Angular, so I'm unsure how to implement that fix. Also, I don't know if the lint errors are related in anyway.

Comment: If in case you switch to NGINX, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51704113/2549787).

Answer (score 0):

What does your deploy script look like? Mine is

`"deploy": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer && firebase deploy --only hosting && cd functions && firebase deploy --only functions"`

After deploying I do not call the functions server

`https://us-central1-your-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/app`

(which gives me the same error as for you)

but the hosting server instead:

`https://your-project-name.firebaseapp.com`

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem instead of destinations you need to add function and point to function name. Like so:

```
"public": "dist",
   "rewrites": [
     {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "app"
  }
],
```

Also it wouldn't hurt to fix the lint errors they are basically saying that you need add `.catch()` for each `.then()` that you use.