# Server-side rendering with Rendertron - Angular 5 without firebase

Tags: angular, fetch, angular5, server-side-rendering

I am using rendertron as a solution for server side rendering, below is index.js file. How to execute index.js and where to execute. I have setup my own instance of redertron using docker on my server and my angular app build is within dist folder how to render complete html of my angular app using rendertron and where to execute index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = require('url');
const app = express('');

const appUrl = 'http://xyzabc.com';
const renderUrl = 'http://pqr.com/render';


    function generateUrl(request) {
        return url.format({
            protocol: request.protocol,
            host: appUrl,
            pathname: request.originalUrl
        });
    }
    function detectBot(userAgent){
        const bots = [
            'bingbot',
            'yandexbot',
            'duckduckbot',
            'slurp',
            //Social
            'twitterbot',
            'facebookexternalhit',
            'linkedinbot',
            'embedly',
            'pinterest',
            'W3C_Validator'
        ]

        const agent = userAgent.toLowerCase();

        for (const bot of bots) {
            if (agent.indexOf(bot) > -1) {
                console.log('bot detected', bot, agent);
                return true;
            }
        }

        console.log('no bots found');
        return false;
    }
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    const isBot = detectBot(req.headers['user-agent']);

    if (isBot) {
        const botUrl = generateUrl(req);

        fetch(`${renderUrl}/${botUrl}`)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(body => {
                res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
                res.set('Vary', 'User-Agent');

                res.send(body.toString())
            });
    } else {
        fetch(`https://${appUrl}/`)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(body => {
                res.send(body.toString());
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using an Angular 6 app and I was facing the same issue. I did it without using an express server or firebase, instead I used NGINX to check the agent header and route them to rendertron if it's a bot or to the angular app if it's a normal user.

Incase, if you wanted to take this approach using NGINX. Use this configuration.

```
server {
    server_name your-server-name;

    root /path to your dist;

    index index.html;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location @prerender {
        set $prerender 0;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }

        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_|prerender=1") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }

        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            rewrite .* /render/$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass https://render-tron.appspot.com; #You can use our own hosted Rendertron
        }

        if ($prerender = 0) {
            rewrite .* /index.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, you can now pre-render if it's a bot.

If you still wanted to do it using a express, rendertron offers an express middleware. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron/tree/master/middleware).

I found this NGINX configuration from [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/), you can find something useful for different server or any other approach in their [repo](https://github.com/prerender/prerender).

Answer (score 0):

Is `http://pqr.com/render` your personal rendering server? If not, you have to forward the request to `https://render-tron.appspot.com/render` or deploy Rendertron separately yourself.

Also right now you just assign the created express-instance to a constant (`const app = express('')`), configure it and export it for firebase (which you don't use). Instead you have to run express yourself on a node.js server.

Comment: but this renders on bot side right ?? how to make it render even on client side bcoz i am also using social sharing links for my app which require meta tags.

Comment: no. you see the if-else `if (isBot) { } else { }` in your code? if its true, it forwards the request to a server which is running rendertron. if false, it forwards to the server where you host your production-built Angular app which was compiled into the /dist folder. that's why you have a renderUrl und an appUrl

Comment: I have used if else but i am not getting rendered html on client side even, nothing works. Is it possible for you to provide complete usage steps or repo of angular2 app and rendertron?? I am not able to do anything and achieve as i am trying this since last 2-3 weeks

Comment: I am setting up my blog with Angular/Firebase/Rendertron right now. I could remove the personal configurations and upload the skeleton to github in the next days, if you want. But it's not very different from the tutorial project so I'm not sure if it would help you much.

Comment: Okay. but it will help me to go through the steps. While in tutorial project i am not getting exactly clear idea of what to use how and implement the same.

Comment: @Phil - Can you provide the github url? Even I'm trying to implement the rendertron without using firebase.

Comment: @pm2530 - Have you successfully implemented it? If so, it would be great if you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: Ya I have implemented rendertron but facing issues with the social share as rendertron is rendering stuffs for me but not on client slide only for bot............

Answer (score -1):

You can user aws server architecture once you have setup with aws account you can logged into there and push you are all code into rendertron folder please kindly follow this link

https://medium.com/@aakashbanerjee/deploying-rendertron-on-aws-ec2-8c00a4bb6b1e